# Animation in Blender 3.4 renders only he first frame

Tags: animation

I am currently running into a problem where it only renders the first frame of my animation. I have checked most of my settings but nothing seems to work.

I am running Blender on a Mac Studio M1 Ultra Desktop computer fully spec'd.

[image]

MY FILE - https://blend-exchange.com/b/YOnxdQNd

Comment: Can you show an image of your R/H panel Output Properties in Blender and are you using F12 (Render > Image) or Ctrl-F12 (Render Animation) to do the render?

Comment: Hi , I have tried using both ways of Rendering , from the top panel , and CTRL F12. Both lead to the same issue where I get an error Image should be closer to 1920 X 1088 ? I seem to be able to Render Stills but not Animations I set up unfortanely. Can anyone provide an Email where I can send you my Sample file for Inspection ? Thanks a Million , I am a Designer trying to create a building that Moves. I'm also running Blender on a Mac Studio M1 Ultra if that helps. I can't seem to attach any type of file in here , I would be more than willing to send it to you for your Help . TIA

Comment: We don't do email here but you can share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page as long as your Blend file isn't too large.

Comment: Thanks my Friend ! I surely attached the file , please if someone can figure out why my Computer doesn't want to render out an animation , I would be very Thankful for your help on This. Thats unfortunate that I can't email somebody about this. Anyways , Thanks again and I look forward to your Help

Comment: You didn't add the link to your file so we can't download it!

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: I apologize for not adding the link , but I think I got it right this time. The animation plays out , but won't render Out when I hit "Render Animation" something is not right. I hope the attached file and screenshots will help make things more clear. But Overall , I Love Blender and want to get this issue resolved soon. TIA

Comment: I just changed the Output path to my desktop in your file and rendered 30  frames without issues here. Do you have a GPU in your machine because I see that your render device is set to CPU rather than GPU. GPU would be much faster if you have a resonable one.

Comment: Wow , Yes I think I have a decent GPU , 64 core. Let me see if that's the Problem , Thank you so much for your insight. I hope this works out , Thanks again my friend.

Comment: Just tried rendering with GPU , I still get only 1 frame and that's it , I get an error that the Image needs to be closer to 1920 x 1088 ?? I'm clueless as to why

Comment: It's set to 1920x1080 (not 1088) under Output Properties > Format in the file you uploaded so I don't know where that error is coming from.